# LXML namespace prefix

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Why doesn't the following 'normal' XPath work using lxml:

```
# Note: "Rows" is obviously not a real namespace, but for internal segmentation
xml_str = '''
<Data xmlns:R="Rows" xmlns:C="Columns" xmlns:V="Values">
    <R:ProductGroup value="Electronics">
    <R:Product value="Computer">
        <C:Year value="2018">
            <V:SumOfRevenue value="104"/>
            <V:SumOfUnits   value="3"/>
        </C:Year>
        <C:Year value="2019">
            <V:SumOfRevenue value="82"/>
            <V:SumOfUnits   value="9"/>
        </C:Year>
        <C:Year value="(all)">
            <V:SumOfRevenue value="186"/>
            <V:SumOfUnits   value="12"/>
            </C:Year>
        </R:Product>
    </R:ProductGroup>
</Data>
'''

from lxml import etree
node=etree.fromstring(xml_str)
```

`//R:ProductGroup[@value="Electronics"]` is a valid XPath by the standards and works in several other utilities but it seems [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) has a very odd way of addressing namespaces:

```
node.xpath('//R:ProductGroup[@value="Electronics"]', namespaces={'R':'Rows'})
[<Element {Rows}ProductGroup at 0x7f05836bec08>]
```

Is it possible to address the namespace without defining it as a dict next to the xpath?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  Do you get an error?

Comment: @JohnGordon updated it -- it 'works' I'm just wondering if it can be done without using that namespace map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily more elegant than using namespaces, but this gets you to the same place:

```
node.xpath('//*[local-name()="ProductGroup"][@value="Electronics"]')
```

Output:

```
[<Element {Rows}ProductGroup at 0x1790b6fb240>]
```

Comment: thanks -- out of curiosity, why does lxml require the namespace as a separate dictionary, and cannot just map it directly via `//Rows:ProductGroup`  ?

Comment: You can do it with xpath 3.1 ( `/*:element_name` or '`/Q{url}element_name`). Unfortunately, lxml only support xpath 1.0 and, to my knowledge, no python library supports xpath 3.1, though elementpath supports xpath 2.0.